# Blur focus with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery dialog that I've loaded content into. When I display the dialog the focus is set to the first item displayed. Normally this is not a problem, but I would prefer that none of the items have explicit focus. How can I blur the focus? Or perhaps set it to the dialog itself?

The dialog's HTML ID is "dialog". I've tried `$("#dialog").focus()` and `$("#dialog :button").blur()` to no avail.

Here's a picture of the dialog:

[image]

Comment: none of the answers so far have worked :-(

Answer (score 0):

Calling Blur will trigger the blur event nothing else.

For take the focus out the textbox try $("#dialog").click();

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/Dpk2j/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // putting a value into a button we don't want focused
  $('#mybutton').val('Here I am.');
  // doing something visual to see when focus happens more clearly
  $("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).next("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);
  });
  // focus on the right input
  $('#dialog').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mE5fx/

```
 open:function(){
     $(this).attr('tabindex',-1).css('outline',0).focus(); 
  }
```